# any way to get BindingResult for @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I'm using Spring 3 Portlet MVC. Validation/binding in just MVC should be the same.

I've got just a single `int` form field. When I'm doing

```
void doSmth(MyForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ... {
  int bindErrors = bindingResult.getErrorCount())
  ...
```

and submitting a field value that can't be parsed as `int` this method gets executed and `bindErrors` is 1. Form field value that this method receives is 0. That's great.

But creating a form just to contain a single field is not great.

I'm changing the code to:

```
void doSmth(@RequestParam int userId, BindingResult bindingResult) ... {
  int bindErrors = bindingResult.getErrorCount())
  ...
```

and getting *Portlet not available* message in browser and this Exception:

> org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet processRequest Could
>   not complete request
>                                    org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q"

Question: is there any way to proceed with method execution and to process binding errors in it even if `@RequestParam` type conversion fails? I tried making `@RequestParam` not required and providing a default value to it - didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spring reference allows BindingResult only for command or form objects.

> org.springframework.validation.Errors / org.springframework.validation.BindingResult validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument).

[(15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

So you may need to implement it by your own.

- I think you can try to use a Custom [MethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) (see this [blog](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/learn-to-customize-spring-mvc-controller-method-arguments/) for an example).
- There is an other current still open stack overflow question: [How to customize parameter names when binding spring mvc command objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8986593/280244) -- I have the feeling that an solution for this question may can give you an good input for your solution.

or you wrap your single `int` in a command object and the use the binding result on this object (an example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407434/280244)

Comment: well if it's not supported out of the box then I think I can live with a single value bean, thanks