# How to validate query parameters count?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have some problems with how spring binds parameters.

In my scenario I want a controller method that accepts only one query argument 'q':

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

   @RequestMapping
   public void test(@RequestParam(value = "q") final String q) {
        System.out.println("> " + q);
   }

}
```

Now if I send the valid request in terms of my specification:

```
GET /home?q=cat
```

I get expected output:

```
> cat
```

And if I send the request that is not valid in terms of my specification, but remains valid as http request:

```
GET /home?q=cat&q=black
```

I get ambiguous and unexpected result ( *I have idea about why spring doing it... arrays binding, etc. :) But it remains a surprise.* ):

```
> cat,black
```

I can't use those parameters, they are can be invalid. 
But I have no simple way to validate request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the parameter as `List<String>` and assert that it only has one single item.

```
@RequestMapping
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "q") final List<String> q) {

    if (q.size() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multiple 'q' parameters are not allowed.");
    }

    System.out.println("> " + q);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is a first workaround which I used up (String[] in my case :) ).  I'm looking for more elegant and 'springy' way to do it. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: You can try then the techniques described in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6203740/1276804).

Comment: Okay, I cant found much more elegant solution :) Sad sad.