# Hibernate Validator @NotBlank without @NotNull

Tags: spring, validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using `Hibernate Validator` annotations with individual parameters of my Spring `@Controller`, as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.SOME_URI, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> tryValidation(
            @Size(min = 1, max = 20) 
            @NotBlank @RequestParam(required = false) String something) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(something);
    }
```

As per my understanding, `@NotBlank` and `@NotEmpty` both use `@NotNull`, but what if I want to use `@NotBlank` without `@NotNull`? Basically, I want the parameter to not be mandatory, but when it is defined it should not be null or empty. However, when I try to do this, the `@RequestParam(required = false)` doesn't matter and you end up having to define the parameter.

I know I could write a custom validator but is there a way to do so within the existing functionality of `Hibernate Validator`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Web MVC - validate individual request params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203740/spring-web-mvc-validate-individual-request-params)

Comment: Actually, I did see this post but the question is not the same. I already know how to validate individual params and I'm already doing it as shown in the code. I want to know if a built-in mechanism allows `@NotBlank` without making the parameter mandatory.

Comment: Use `@Length` annotation with `min=1`

Comment: That works! Thanks, @Roman Proshin! By the way, what is the difference between `@Size` and `@Length`?

Comment: @ystark Good question! I found next differences: `Length` - from hibernate lib, but `Size` - from javax.validation. `Length` - for strings only, `Size` - for string and collections. It looks like `Size` is more universal.

Comment: @Roman Proshin, you're right about that. Thanks again!

Comment: `@Length` with `min=1` will allow blank fields though. `" "` passes with a length minimum >= 1, however it would not pass `@NotBlank`.