# Spring MVC - POST a list of files with max count limit

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@PostMapping(value = "/upload",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseBody uploadAttachments(
        @RequestParam(value = "comment", required = true) String comment,
        @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files
) {
    /* do magic */
}
```

I'm using this mapping to process a form with attachments. It consumes `multipart/form-data`.

How can I limit the maximum number of attached files to 10?

Comment: maybe you should focus more on the total size of files rather than the number of files? if you limit the number (i dont know how right now though) you may still get 10 files of 1GB each? just an observation

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. I've already restricted `max-file-size` to 2MB and `max-request-size` to 20MB. And now I'm looking for a way to put restrictions on the list size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203740/spring-web-mvc-validate-individual-request-params maybe this might be of some help to you

Comment: @masadwin Thank you! this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212603/1429387) was helpful for me. I used `@Size(max = 10)` annotation on my `files` parameter. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: thank you. glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as indicated in this answer [Spring Web MVC - validate individual request params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203740/spring-web-mvc-validate-individual-request-params)

use `@Size(max = ?)` annotation on your parameter to limit the input size