# JSR - 349 bean validation for Spring @RestController with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation, jsr

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE and not able to incorporate JSR - 349 ( bean validation 1.1 ) for `@RequestParam` & `@PathVariable` at method itself.

For POST requests, if method parameter is a Java POJO then annotating that parameter with `@Valid` is working fine but annotating `@RequestParam` & `@PathVariable` with something like `@NotEmpty`, `@Email` not working.

I have annotated controller class with Spring's `@Validated`

There are lots of questions on SO and I have commented on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203740/spring-web-mvc-validate-individual-request-params/39212603#comment75615588_39212603) that its not working for me.

Spring Boot includes - `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` and `hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar` .

Am I missing anything?

Example code ,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testValidated", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseBean<String> testValidated(@Email @NotEmpty @RequestParam("email") String email) {
    ResponseBean<String> response = new ResponseBean<>();
    response.setResponse(Constants.SUCCESS);
    response.setMessage("testValidated");
    logger.error("Validator Not called");
    return response; 
}
```

Below handler is never called when I send empty values or not well formed email address for `email` & control always goes to with in `testValidated` method.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseBean handle(ConstraintViolationException exception) {

    StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
    ResponseBean response = new ResponseBean();

    exception.getConstraintViolations().forEach(entry -> messages.append(entry.getMessage() + "\n"));

    response.setResponse(Constants.FAILURE);
    response.setErrorcode(Constants.ERROR_CODE_BAD_REQUEST);
    response.setMessage(messages.toString());
    return response;
}
```

`ResponseBean<T>` is my application specific class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had asked the question after more than two days of unsuccessful hit & trial. Lots of confusing answers are out there because of confusions around Spring Validations and JSR validations, how Spring invokes JSR validators, changes in JSR standards & types of validations supported.

Finally, [this article](http://apprize.info/javascript/wrox/16.html) helped a lot.

I solved problem in two steps,

1.Added following beans to my `Configuration` - without these beans , nothing works.

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor mvProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    mvProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return mvProcessor;
}           

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
    return validator;
}
```

2.Placed Spring's @Validated annotation on my controller like below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/...")
@Validated
public class MyRestController {
}
```

Validated is - `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated`

This set up doesn't affected `@Valid` annotations for `@RequestBody` validations in same controller and those continued to work as those were.

So now, I can trigger validations like below for methods in `MyRestController` class,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testValidated" , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseBean<String> testValidated(
        @Email(message="email RequestParam is not a valid email address") 
        @NotEmpty(message="email RequestParam is empty") 
        @RequestParam("email") String email) {
    ResponseBean<String> response = new ResponseBean<>();
    ....
    return response; 
}
```

I had to add another handler in exception handler for exception - `ConstraintViolationException` though since `@Validated` throws this exception while `@Valid` throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

Answer (score 0):

Spring @Validated @Controller did not mapped when adding @Validated. Removal of any inheritance from controller itself did help. Otherwise Sabir Khan's answer worked and did help.